# Azure Management Groups and IAM

Tags: azure

I am unable to add an AAD group to an Azure Management Group (MG). When I go too add the group, I can see it and select it, but the Save button is grayed out. I can add users to the MG and can also add the same AAD group to Azure subscriptions residing underneath the MG. I have full rights in both Azure and AAD.

Thank you in advance for you help,
Rick

Answer (score 0):

Azure Management Groups work a bit differently than an Azure Owner is used to.  You initially need a Global Administrator to give themselves access to User Access Administrator role.  Then they'll be able to go into the Root Management Group, assign whoever access to manage the Root Management Group which will flow down to Management Groups under it.  Then the Global Administrator can remove themselves from User Access Administrator Role.

See here for more information: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/overview